# Converting List to Set in Python! What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I created a list with random letters(uppercase & lowercase). Im trying to write code so it only print the unique values considering the uppercase & lowercase. for example, ["A","a","a","B","b"] would print ["a","b"]

heres my code so far:

```
List_1 = ["a","a","a","b","A","b", "B", "c", "C"]
for x in List_1:
    l = x.lower()
    myset = set(l)
    print(myset)
```

& here is the output:

```
{'a'}
{'a'}
{'a'}
{'b'}
{'a'}
{'b'}
{'b'}
{'c'}
{'c'}
```

Now that im printing these value through a set, why is it still printing duplicate values? what am  I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You are doing wrong that you create a new set in each loop iteration.

Instead of

> ```
> myset = set(l)
> ```

you want to use

```
myset.add(l)
```

and initialize `myset = set()` before the loop.

Alternatively, you can replace the whole loop by a *set comprehension*:

```
myset = {x.lower() for x in List_1}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're taking every single element in the list, then making a set with that - each set has no knowledge of the other set.

Try something like this:

```py
myset = set(l.lower() for l in List_1)
```

You'll end up with a true set.

Comment: So basically combine line 2,3,&4??

Comment: The list comprehension is unnecessary; `set` can iterate over a generate expression itself. `set(l.lower() for l in List_1)`.

Comment: @MoinChaudhry You have to convert all to lower and finally the `set()` takes the values and removes duplicates passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution iterates over the list and *creates a singleton set for each item in the list*, which it then prints and throws away.

To convert a list to a set, simply write `set(the_list)`.

In your case, you first want to transform the list (by lower-casing the letters). This can be done via list comprehension, which creates a new list. Or you could use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), which can be directly passed to the `set` constructor without first creating a temporary list:

```
result = set(s.lower() for s in the_list)
```

And lastly, Python has special syntactic sugar for this construct, using *set comprehension*, which is shown in mkrieger1’s answer.